# Setting JavaScript Object literal value

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a JS object as follows;

```
var UserDataObj = {
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com",
    phone: "9999999999",
    desc: "some description"
}
```

Now this is a global var.

Inside one of my function to save form data,

I have

```
$(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr("name");
    var value = $(this).val();
    UserDataObj.key = value;
})
```

Now I want to update the default values in UserDataObj with the values entered by the user.
I am not sure if the line UserDataObj.key = value; is correct

I need the key to correspond to the object property..I have the same name...

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
UserDataObj[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Original object:

```
var UserDataObj = {
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com",
    phone: "9999999999",
    desc: "some description"
}
```

Setup and populate new object:

```
var userData = {};

$(".formFieldUserData").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    userData[$this.attr("name")] = $this.val();
});
```

Merge new data into the data we already have:

```
$.extend(UserDataObj, userData);
```

Note: `$.extend` will modify the `UserDataObj` to contain both old and new data.